# Formatting date inside a custom itemRenderer for Spark List

Tags: list, apache-flex, formatting, itemrenderer, flex-spark

I would like to efficiently format a date property for a Spark list that uses a custom ItemRenderer. All the dates should be formatted the same so I really do not want to instantiate a new DateTimeFormatter for each list item. How can I use a single DateTimeFormatter to format the property data.lastModified in the below example?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:ItemRenderer xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
                autoDrawBackground="true">
    <mx:VBox height="100%" width="100%" paddingBottom="10" paddingTop="10" paddingLeft="10" paddingRight="10">
        <s:Label text="{data.name}" fontSize="16" height="100%"/>
        <mx:HBox width="100%">
            <s:Label text="{data.client}"/>
            <s:Label width="100%" text="{data.lastModified}" textAlign="right"/>
        </mx:HBox>
    </mx:VBox>
</s:ItemRenderer>
```

Here is the use:

```
<s:List id="projectsList" left="12" top="172" bottom="10" width="303"
                    dataProvider="{projectsArray}" itemRenderer="ProjectListItemRenderer"></s:List>
```

Answer (score 2):

Define your DateFormatter in ActionScript and make it static.  Kind of like this:

```
public static var dateFormatter : DateFormatter = new DateFormatter();
```

This will create a single instance of the DateFormatter no matter how many instances of the class you have.  You'll have to access the DateFormatter using the class name, though.  If you need to set properties on the DateFormatter you can do so in a static method; kind of like this:

```
public static var dateFormatter : DateFormatter = ThisClass.createDateFormatter();

public static function createDateFormatter():DateFormatter{
  var df :DateFormatter = new DateFormatteR():
  df.dateStyle = DateTimeStyle.MEDIUM;
  return df;
}
```